# How to create "RoleManager<IdentityRole>" in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am unable to use RoleManager in my application. I am trying to seed an Admin user in to a .NET Core web application, and I want this user to have a role called "canEdit". What I've got currently produces this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' has been registered.'

I have tried various ways of doing this. I have tried using Service Provider to do it, dependency injection, etc. but they all give the same error.

ServiceProvider in the Configure method of Startup.cs:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();

var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
DbInitializer dbi = new DbInitializer(roleManager);
dbi.Initialize(context, userManager);
```

DBInitializer Class:

Constructor:

```
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> rm;

    public DbInitializer(RoleManager<IdentityRole> rm)
    {
        this.rm = rm;
    }
```

CreateAdmin method:

```
private async Task CreateAdmin(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        IdentityResult ir;
        ir = await rm.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("canEdit"));
        IdentityRole canEdit = new IdentityRole("canEdit");
        ApplicationUser admin = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "Member1@email.com"
        };
        if (context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == admin.UserName).Count() == 0)
        {
            userManager.CreateAsync(admin, "Password123!").Wait();
            userManager.AddToRoleAsync(admin, "canEdit").Wait();
        }
    }
```

CreateUsers method:

```
private void CreateUsers(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {

        CreateAdmin(userManager, context).Wait();

        ApplicationUser customer1 = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = "Customer1@email.com"
        };
        if (context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == customer1.UserName).Count() > 0)
        {
            userManager.CreateAsync(customer1, "Password123!").Wait();
        }
```

This repeats for customer2, 3, 4, 5. I can optimise this by removing the need to create an object which I may not need (in the case where the email exists), but I was trying to knock up this method and the CreateAdmin method quickly, then optimise later. Unfortunately I then ran in to an error which I have been unable to fix.

The end goal is for the DbInitializer class to seed 5 regular users, and 1 admin user with extra permissions/claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the Identity services registered?
Also, I ran into issues when I used .Wait() instead of await.

```
  services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(options=>
        {
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;               
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;      

        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddDefaultUI()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

If this helps, here is how I seeded my Db.

```
  public SeedDataBase(IServiceProvider _serviceProvider, ApplicationDbContext _context)
    {
        serviceProvider = _serviceProvider;
        context = _context;

    }
    private IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
    private ApplicationDbContext context;
    private ApplicationUser superUser;

    public async Task Seed()
    {

        await CreateSuperUser();
        await SeedDb();
    }
    private async Task CreateSuperUser()
    {
        var _userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var userExists = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("FULLADMIN");

        if (userExists.Count() < 1)
        {
            var _roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var _signinManger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

            superUser = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "superuser@superuser.com",
                Email = "superuser@superuser.com",
                FirstName = "Super",
                LastName = "User",
                AccountCreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                Access = ApplicationUser.Permissions.FullAdmin
            };
            var permissions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ApplicationUser.Permissions));

            foreach (var s in permissions)
            {
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(s));
            }
            await _userManager.CreateAsync(superUser, "SecureP@ssword1234");
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(superUser, Enum.GetName(typeof(ApplicationUser.Permissions), superUser.Access));
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the ConfigureServices method, I have: services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); I will try editing it to see if that works.

Comment: Sure thing, I updated to show how I seeded my db. Not the prettiest code (its old), but it may help.

Comment: services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddRoleStore<IUserRoleStore<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>(); I have changed it to this, and it all compiles except for adding the role store.

Comment: The error I get is: System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]' for service type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.' I believe the problem is all the RoleStore classes being interfaces, but I can't work out how to do it with any other class. All the RoleStores are interfaces.

Comment: Changing it back to AddDefaultIdentity, and simply using ".AddRoles<IdentityRole>()" has seeded the users now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IdentityServer4 or Duende.IdentityServer in .NET 5 < with Individual user accounts then edit `Startup.cs`. Look for the following values:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Edit it to look like this:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Comment: The ".AddRoles" line did it for me. I was following a guide on how to manipulate roles, and the guide said to use DI for the roles controller but didn't spell out what to add to Startup.cs/Program.cs to enable said DI.

Answer (score 0):

that may help someone in the future ,
you have to use the `await` for the `RoleManager.CreateAsync` method

then to verify if the operation was completed successfully

```
var res = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Role));
if(res.Succeeded)
{
    return Ok("created successfully !");
}
```